# How can I make a span element cover a button completely?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a problem with the button id="button_1".  I have to click on the span element id="playButton" to start a function. The problem is the size of the span element. As an inline element the span is smaller than the button. Therefore, not every click starts the underlying function.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve the problem? I have tried to change the span into a div and change the height and width, but it is still smaller than the button.

Many thanks.

```css
#button {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 14px 40px;
}

#playButton {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
}

#pauseButton {
  display: none;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button_1">
    <span id="playButton">Open</span>
    <span id="pauseButton">Close</span>
</button>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you have a script which toggles those spans to change the button label. Why not just change the button text instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

button tag has a default value from HTML itself = padding : 1px 6px
so you need to make

```
#button {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

and for some space for span

```
padding: 3px
```

Answer (score 0):

**What you asked**

1. Make the spans `inline-block` so they have size.
2. Move the padding from the button to the span.

```css
#button {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#button span {
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 40px;
}

span#playButton {
  display: block;
}

span#pauseButton {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button">
    <span id="playButton">Open</span>
    <span id="pauseButton">Close</span>
</button>
```

**What I'd do instead**

1. Disable pointer events on the spans (not even necessary, really).
2. Apply click handler to button itself, using a class or data attribute to track state.

```css
#button {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 14px 40px;
}

#button span {
  pointer-events: none;
}

span#playButton {
  display: block;
}

span#pauseButton {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button">
    <span id="playButton">Open</span>
    <span id="pauseButton">Close</span>
</button>
```